# Composer keeps .svn directory when dev-trunk used, but not when a specific tag is specified on wpackagist packages

Tags: svn, composer-php, wpackagist

I'm using composer to deploy a WordPress app which contains several plugins. For privately hosted plugins, I'm using satis. For public plugins, some are hosted on github, whilst others (the majority) are using the wpackagist service.

I've noticed that, when `require`ing a `wpackagist-plugin`, if I specify an exact tag for the package (i.e. `1.0.2`), the plugin is installed *without* any .svn directory. However, if I use `dev-trunk`, the plugin directory contains a .svn directory.

Is it possible to keep the .svn directory when using a specific tag? (Is there a specific composer.json config I can specify to always keep the vcs directory, for example?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Composer downloads distributions (e.g. tar archives) for stable versions and uses `git clone`/`svn co` for unstable versions (branches).

You can change this behaviour with 2 command line options: `--prefer-dist` (meaning: use distributions even for unstable versions) and `--prefer-source` (use `git clone`/`svn co` for stable versions).

Comment: In addition: This works only if Composer knows the location of a ZIP or repository. If it doesn't, you cannot checkout a repo instead of a ZIP or vice versa. That's why it is called "prefer".